# codigniter multiple image upload function deletes the image while updating another fields of form

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I need help I seriously don't now what's happening here could not find any solution

Below is my code for updating an form and its include image upload also

this is update code inside controller

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('avatar','avatar','callback_multiple_image_upload|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('overview','overview','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('history','history','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pre_experience','pre_experience','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('education','education','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('joining','joining','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hobbies','hobbies','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('experience','experience','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('skills','skills','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('record','record','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('achievements','achievements','trim');


    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
            // check if avatar is uploaded
        $images = ($this->session->userdata('uploaded_images'))?$this->session->userdata('uploaded_images'):array();
        if($this->session->userdata('uploaded_avatar')){
            $user['avatar'] = $this->session->userdata('uploaded_avatar');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('uploaded_avatar');
        }

        $data = array(
                'avatar' => ($images)?$images[0]['file_name']:'',
                'thumb' => ($images)?$images[0]['thumb']:'',
                'overview' =>$this->input->post('overview'),
                'history' =>$this->input->post('history'),
                'pre_experience' =>$this->input->post('pre_experience'),
                'education' =>$this->input->post('education'),
                'joining' =>$this->input->post('joining'),
                'hobbies' =>$this->input->post('hobbies'),
                'experience' =>$this->input->post('experience'),
                'skills' =>$this->input->post('skills'),
                'record' =>$this->input->post('record'),
                'achievements' =>$this->input->post('achievements'),
                'modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

        );
        $this->user_model->update($user_id,$data,'user_id');


    }
```

everytimes if i update only image then it updates it and display sucess messages 
but as i update any of the field from the form like if i update overview field then also it display success message but it deletes the image from db and display error message also you didn't select any file to upload

please help me what should i do i tried various times but with no luck

here is my multiple upload function

```
public function multiple_image_upload()
    {
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/user_avatars/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 10000;
        $config['max_width']            = 10240;
        $config['max_height']           = 7680;

        //$images = array();

        if(isset($_FILES['avatar']) && ($count = count($_FILES['avatar']['name'])) > 0)
        {
            $files = $_FILES;
            $images = array();
            /* check if folder with year exists*/
            $current_year = date('Y');
            $path = './uploads/user_avatars/'.$current_year;

            if(is_dir($path)){
                /* do nothing */
            }else{
                /* create directory */
                @mkdir( $path , 0755, true );
            }

            $images = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
            {
                $config['upload_path'] = $path;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '100000';
                $config['max_width']  = '102400';
                $config['max_height']  = '76800';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
                {
                    $data = $this->upload->data();

                    /* create thumbnail */
                    $this->load->helper('image_thumb_helper');
                    generate_image_thumb($data['full_path'],$path,$data['file_name']);

                    /* add to database */                   
                    $images[$i]['file_name'] = $current_year.'/'.$data['file_name'];
                    $images[$i]['thumb'] = $current_year.'/thumb_'.$data['file_name'];
                }else{
                    $this->form_validation->set_message('multiple_image_upload',$this->upload->display_errors());
                    return false; 
                }    
            }

            $this->session->set_userdata('uploaded_images',$images);
            return true;
        }
        else{

          return true;
        }
    }
```

Your help would BE appreciated